# Data mapping to Excel files

Tags: excel, file, matlab, unix

I have 635 text files in one folder. I want to read this data into excel. This is not as straightforward  a task as it sounds at first. I've been working on exporting the files to excel(with the help of **stackoverflow** :)) and now that I have got that working, I want to finish my application. Here are the parameters:

1. My output excel spreadsheet will have 637 columns and data would be entered from the third column onward. As you can guess, each column(3-639) will represent one of the 635 sub-folders.
2. There are 73902 rows in the spreadsheet and the data will be written from the 3rd row onward.
3. Now, the data to be written comes from the 635 files. Every file has 2 columns. For example to fill out column 5(which will correspond to **5-2 = 3rd file out of 635**) in the excel sheet, we go to the **3rd** file and take the values from there.The first column in that file determines what cells to be filled out in the excel sheet. The values to be filled out are taken from the second column of this file(Sorry if the word column is getting confusing). We need to fill out 73900 rows for every column on the sheet(every column is 1 file). And then repeat this for 635 columns.

If the 3rd file looks like this:

```
5849 66883
395 4492863
681 1835871
817 4039961
835 3246671
868 4041156
889 1891481
1305 4467688
1317 175306
1361 3252611
2101 174589
4364 4053046
4897 4466547
4991 3879532
5327 3992891
5397 175328
6067 3881675
6075 176782
6906 2358727
7497 1838021
```

then we will fill out rows `5849, 385, 681,817` and so on...We fill these cells with the corresponding values from the second column in the file. So the 5th column in the excel sheet will have the cells `5849, 385, 681,817...` filled with values `66883,4492863,1835871,4039961...`

I am attaching an image of the excel sheet to make the situation clearer [image]

So far I have the Visual Basic code to import text files into Excel but don't really process any of the info discussed above. I also have a small MATLAB script to do the same(this is not completely functioning) to write data to excel. I am pasting both below.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

 ' get the directory you want
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder("D:\275_25bp")

' set the starting point to write the data to
 Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
' Open the file
Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

' Read the file one line at a time
Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
    TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

    ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
    Items = Split(TextLine, " ")

    ' Put data on one row in active sheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
        cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
    Next

    ' Move to next row
    Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

' Clean up
FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

**####################### MATLAB SCRIPT################################**

```
dirname = uigetdir;#
Files = dir(fullfile(dirname,'*.txt'))
for i=1:numel(Files)
filename = fullfile(dirname,Files(k).name);
[col1,col2] = textread( filename, '%d%d' )
%pos1 = strcat('A',num2str(i));
%pos2 = strcat('B',num2str(i));
xlswrite('sample_output',col1,'Sheet1','A1:CI1')
xlswrite('sample_output',col2,'Sheet1','A2:CI2')
end
```

There's no general naming pattern for the file-NAMES except that they are unique names. The folder contains them alphabetically, so file 1(starting with A) and file 635(will start with Z).Sample file names:

`Acidothermus_cellulolyticus_11B-list.txt`

`Frankia_alni_ACN14a-list.txt`
`...`
`Zymomonas_mobilis_ZM4-list.txt`

It doesn't matter what language is used, but preferably something in UNIX(I know this is not a language :P ) or MATLAB(as I have been doing this project in these 2 languages).

I'd greatly appreciate help with this. Please let me if you need any clarification on what needs to be done. Thank you!

Comment: old excels only allow 64K rows. Better check that first. Maybe a 64bit Windows7 will solve that issue. Good luck.

Comment: Would you consider using PERL (usually available on UNIX) to do the processing and create a CSV file?  Not sure if it can open all of the files at once, but given the amount of data, it can probably contain everything in memory and then be written out at the end of processing.  Are all of the files in the same directory and is there a unique order in which they need to be processed?  How are the files named?

Comment: I am using windows 7, 64 bit and already checked the # of columns and # of rows and it works. @Glenn:Yes perl works, I can download the perl extension for cygwin.

Comment: Yes all the files are in the same directory. I'm going to edit the question to include sample file names. They need to be processed alphabetically as the fifth column in the excel sheet, which corresponds to the 3rd file(alphabetically) in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use PERL,  here is the PERL code/script I generated to create a CSV file which can be ingested by Excel, based on the information above.  All the files have to be in the same directory.  I have syntax checked it.  You may have to make some edits to direcotory path and the filename in the **glob** function (such as name with a wildcard of *). The input to **glob** will find all of the files with a .dat extension in the local directory.  Be sure to use backslashes if you put in a path. The files will be processed are in alphabitical order as the sort function doing a aphlabitical sort.

If you are using Window 7, you might want to take a look at ActiveState PERL.  That way you don't have to download and install of cygwin.  You can run it from the command window.  It is what I used to syntax check the PERL script, and I have Windows 7, 64 bit.

**NOTE: Updated the code below to what worked with cygwin PERL.  There are still debug items left in from the efforts. **

```
use strict; 
#use File::Glob ':glob'; 

# Array to save the data 
my @savedData = (); 

# Get the files to process and sort them 
# NOTE: Edit for where the files exist if not 
# local directory from where script is run 
my @files = sort <*.txt>; 
print "number of files " . scalar(@files) . "\n"; # should be <*.txt> 
# Will shift columns on the output 
my $column = 0; 
# Save the numbers from the line 
my @numbers = (); 
my $lineNumber = 0; 

# Go through the files 
foreach my $f ( @files ) 
{ 
  # Open the file 
  #print "Processing file: $f\n"; 
  my %temp = (); 
  open INFILE,$f or die "Unable to open file: $f"; 

  # Read a line from the file 
  while ( <INFILE> ) 
  { 
    # Increment the line number, remove the carriage return 
    $lineNumber++; 
    chomp; 
    # Get the numbers from the line 
    @numbers = split("\\s+"); 
    # Check for error in amount of items 
    if ( 2 != scalar(@numbers)) 
    { 
      die "ERROR: Line not well formed in file: $f Line: $lineNumber\n"; 
    } 
    # Save the information using the first number as the row 
    $savedData[$numbers[0]][$column] = $numbers[1]; 
    $temp{$numbers[0]} = 1; 
    #print "$column $savedData[$numbers[0]][$column] "; 
    #print "@numbers\n"; 
  } 

  # Close the file and increment the column by 2 
  close(INFILE); 
  $column++; 
  my @keys = keys %temp; 
  @keys = sort { $a <=> $b} @keys; 
  #thisprint "Range of row indexes is: $keys[0] $keys[$#keys]\n "; # gives the range of rows 
} 

# Loop Control Variable 
my $lcv = 0; 
# Variable to save output 
my $output = ""; 
# Open output file 
# NOTE: File will be opened in current directory 
open OUTFILE,">output.csv" or die "Unable to open output file: output.csv"; 

# TO PRINT ROWS FROM 3RD POSTION 
#print OUTFILE ",,,\n,,,\n"; # can remove this 

#print "Scalar is " . scalar(@savedData) . "\n"; 
# For each row in the matrix 

# For each row in the matrix 
#for( $lcv = 1; $lcv < scalar(@savedData) ; $lcv++ ) 
#{ 
# construct the output for all of the columns 
# Two columns is to shift the output over by 2 columns 
#my $lcv2; 
#$output = ","; 
#print "items is: " . ref($savedData[$lcv]) . "\n"; 
#for($lcv2=0;$lcv2 < scalar(@files); $lcv2++) 
#{ 
#$output .= ",$savedData[$lcv][$lcv2]"; 
#} 
# write it to file 
#print OUTFILE "$output\n"; 
#} 

#close(OUTFILE); 

# For each row in the matrix 
for( $lcv = 1; $lcv < scalar(@savedData) ; $lcv++ ) 
{ 
  # construct the output for all of the columns 
  # Two columns is to shift the output over by 2 columns 
  my $lcv2; 
  $output = ","; 
  for($lcv2=0;$lcv2 < scalar(@files); $lcv2++) 
  { 
    $savedData[$lcv][$lcv2] = int($savedData[$lcv][$lcv2] + 0); 
    $output .= ",$savedData[$lcv][$lcv2]"; 
  } 
  # write it to file 
  print OUTFILE "$output\n"; 
} 

close(OUTFILE);
```

Change to implement maps instead of arrays as it seems program was running out of memory.

Here is the changed code.

```
use strict;  

# Map to save the data  
my %savedData = ();  

# Get the files to process and sort them  
# NOTE: Edit for where the files exist if not  
# local directory from where script is run  
my @files = sort <*.txt>;  
print "number of files " . scalar(@files) . "\n"; # should be <*.txt>  
# Will shift columns on the output  
my $column = 0;  
# Save the numbers from the line  
my @numbers = ();  
my $lineNumber = 0; 
my $lastRow = 0;
my $fileCount = 0;

# Go through the files  
foreach my $f ( @files )  
{  
  # Open the file 
  $fileCount++;  
  print "$fileCount: Processing file: $f\n";  
  my %temp = ();  
  open INFILE,$f or die "Unable to open file: $f";  

  # Read a line from the file  
  while ( <INFILE> )  
  {  
    # Increment the line number, remove the carriage return  
    $lineNumber++;  
    chomp;  
    # Get the numbers from the line  
    @numbers = split("\\s+");  
    # Check for error in amount of items  
    if ( 2 != scalar(@numbers))  
    {  
      die "ERROR: Line not well formed in file: $f Line: $lineNumber\n";  
    }  
    # Save the information using the first number as the row  
    $savedData{$numbers[0]}{$column} = $numbers[1];  
    $temp{$numbers[0]} = 1; 
    # Determine the last item in rows.  Save it for 
# future use
    if ( $lastRow < $numbers[0] )
    {
      $lastRow = $numbers[0];
    }

    #print "$column $savedData{$numbers[0]}{$column} ";  
    #print "@numbers\n";  
  }  

  # Close the file and increment the column by 2  
  close(INFILE);  
  $column++;  
  my @keys = keys %temp;  
  @keys = sort { $a <=> $b} @keys;  
  #thisprint "Range of row indexes is: $keys[0] $keys[$#keys]\n "; # gives the range of rows  
}  

# Loop Control Variable  
my $lcv = 0;  
# Variable to save output  
my $output = "";  
# Open output file  
# NOTE: File will be opened in current directory  
open OUTFILE,">output_map.csv" or 
   die "Unable to open output file: output_map.csv";  

# For each row in the matrix  
for( $lcv = 1; $lcv < $lastRow ; $lcv++ )  
{  
  # construct the output for all of the columns  
  # Two columns is to shift the output over by 2 columns  
  my $lcv2;  
  my $data = "";
  $output = ","; 
  for($lcv2=0;$lcv2 < scalar(@files); $lcv2++)  
  {  
    if ( exists $savedData{$lcv}{$lcv2} ) 
    {
      $data = int($savedData{$lcv}{$lcv2} + 0);  
      $output .= ",$data";  
    }
    else
    {
      $output .= ",0";
    }
  }  
  # write it to file  
  print OUTFILE "$output\n";  
}  

close(OUTFILE);
```

Comment: I already have cygwin, I'm installing the perl package as we speak. Are there any changes I'd need to make to this file to run in through cygwin?

Comment: Not that I know of.  This is fairly generic PERL.

Comment: So perl is still installing...I was looking at your code and have a few questions: Why do you do the following?                         1. `if ( 2 != scalar(@numbers))
     {
        die "ERROR: Line not well formed in file: $f Line: $lineNumber\n";
     }`                                                                   2. `close(INFILE);
   $column += 2;`  # The skip by 2 columns in the excel sheet? I jsut wanted to skip the fist 2 columns as they were taken by the headers. No need to skip 2 columns for every file

Comment: 1.  Checks to make sure there are just 2 numbers on the line, no more or no less.  Make sure the inputs are correct.   2. Move over the two columns for the next file.  First file goes in columns 0 and 1, Second file in 2 and 3 and so on and so forth.  The other questions I have is are you meaning rows to skip, and not columns?  I know matlab is column major (columns then row).  What I have written here is row major.

Comment: " Move over the two columns for the next file. First file goes in columns 0 and 1, Second file in 2 and 3 and so on and so forth"--Is this taking place in the excel file(csv for now)? Each file is represented by only 1 column in this excel spreadsheet and has 76900 rows. These rows take the values from the second column of the file and row #s are taken from the first column of the corresponding file. The unused cells can just be filled with zeros. Also, I don't quite understand your question. Would appreciate it if you could clarify it more.

Comment: Gives me the following errors: `Global symbol "@number" requires explicit package name at p1.pl line 38.
Global symbol "@number" requires explicit package name at p1.pl line 39.
`

Comment: Error on my part.  $number[0];  and $number[1]; should be $numbers[0]; and $numbers[1]; Fo rthe previous question, when writing the output to file, I have added ",," which will shift output by two columns, so when Excel reads it, it will read two blank columns and then the rest of the data. In reading the statement again, I think it makes more sense to me now.  Will need to modify the code above to correct that issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9222/discussion-between-glenn-and-dawnoflife)

Comment: Thank you.  Glad I could help.  Love the chat feature.  Worked great.

Comment: Glenn, I am getting a perl.exe.stackdump when I'm running with the larger file

Comment: Does it get through any of the files and then stack dumps?

Comment: Does it indicate why it is stackdumps?  Wonder if it is running out of memory?

Comment: I can't open the stackdump file in notepad (it shows up as empty). it doesn't report anything on the screen either. Yeah that's my guess as well. When I do the `report all indexes` print command it does show me up till 5th from the last reads...

Comment: Have some other ideas which may work.  1) Move to maps instead of arrays for the data.  Not sure if that will fix the issues.  2).  Output the rows in columns and then you would have to do a cut an paste special and transpose the rows and columns.  That way only one file at a time is processed and memory would not be an issue.  Need to go out for a bit.  Will check back when I return.  May have more time to work on it then. Will probably try to do chat again.

Comment: Yeah tried to implement the maps, but with no success. Not quite sure how you'd do the second part...hit me up on chat when you get back :)

Comment: I'm back.  Will edit the solution for the map.  Will see if that works.  Click on add a comment and then the link for the discussion chat above the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate the problem in to that of "getting the data" and "putting it in excel".  It seems that you know how to put the data into Excel, which is excellent, so I'll focus on the first one.

The great thing is that you basically have a big table or matrix, and Matlab likes matrices.  The only thing that might be a problem is that your matrix is very big, and maybe most of it is zeros.  That's fine; we can use a [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) matrix in matlab.

```
data = sparse(nRowMax, nFiles);
```

Then the algorithm is straightforward:

1. For each file...

   1. Determine the column number `col`.
   2. For each line...

      1. Read the line as `row` and `value`
      2. Insert `value` into `data(row, col)`
   3. Repeat 2 until all the lines are read
2. Repeat 1 until all the files are read.
3. `data` now contains all the data in exactly the format you require in the excel spreadsheet.  Export it.

Matlab Code:

```
for col = 1:nFiles
    filename = files(k).filename;
    fileID = fopen(filename);
    filedata = textscan(fileID, "%d %d");

    rownumbers = filedata{1};
    values = filedata{2};

    for i = 1:length(rownumbers)
        row = rownumbers(i);
        value = values(i);
        data(row, col) = value;
    end
end
```

Comment: Have a look at the way I am writing the data to excel. Does it make sense to you? I think there's something wrong with my  ranges in `xlswrite` command--`A1:CI1`

Comment: I don't have the capacity to test at the moment - instead of trying to calculate what the range should be, does it work if you only specify the top-left cell i.e. `'C3'`?